# How can i get result if word wrong or spelling wrong or greek word get english result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can i get result if word wrong or spelling wrong or Greek word enter get English result
example:
in my web site i want to search "jeans" or "jenz" get same result its a simple examples my main concern if user enter same meaning word or wrong greek word but my site develop in English format how can this word search

can any one give me idea how i get solution for this problem my site in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the "spelling wrong" part (Did you mean)**

- You could do some `LIKE` queries in the db e.g. `LIKE %j%e%a%n%s%` but if you want to do it well, you should use a search library like this:

  - https://github.com/TomLingham/Laravel-Searchy
  - http://tnt.studio/blog/did-you-mean-functionality-with-laravel-scout

> You can publish the configuration file to your app directory and
>   override the settings by running php artisan vendor:publish to copy
>   the configuration to your config folder as searchy.php
>
> You can set the default driver to use for searches in the
>   configuration file. Your options (at this stage) are: fuzzy, simple
>   and levenshtein.
>
> You can also override these methods using the following syntax when
>   running a search:

By defining [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) you can finetune how far off a word can be.

- If you need better performance you should consider something like `solr` or `elasticsearch` for this task.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

**For the translation part**

You just should have a dictionary ready in your database or localization files and run the input trough that as well. Expect high computing times for both spelling correction and translation in your code.

Comment: if any other idea like use third party api to solve this issue?

Comment: Algolia is worth a try

Comment: sorry Thomas but i am not sure which is best solr or elstic search because i do't know how to do fast and easy way can you please guide me

Comment: Fastest result is with just the library